# Solve T(1) = 1 T(n) = T(n-1) + n^2 for n ≥ 2

Tags: recurrence-relation, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-analysis

I am not able to solve the following recurrence relation:

$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
   T(n-1) + n^2 & \text{if } n \ge 2, 
   \\
   1 & \text{otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

How do I start?

Comment: Search up the master's theorem in google.

Comment: Sum all the instances of the recurrence for $n=2,3,...,m$ and cancel the terms that appear on both sides. You get $T(m)=T(1)+2^2+3^2+...+m^2=1+2^2+3^2+...+m^2=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}$.

Comment: @nir shahar, that’s quite useless advice. Master’s theorem can’t be used here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the recursion formula T(n) = T(n-1) + g(n), T(1) = c has the solution T(n) = c + sum of g(k) over 2 <= k <= n. No recursion, just a simple summation.

Answer (score 0):

$$T(n)=T(1)+\sum_{i=2}^{n}i^2$$
$$T(n)=T(1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2-\sum_{i=1}^{1}i^2$$

*So as @plop mentioned in comments, we have:*
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=O(n^3)$$